# I want to find xpath of the Customer ID input textbox for https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/

Tags: xpath, element

unable to find xpath for the Customer Id input_textbox fot https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/

team give me a solution

My code:

```
public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/"); 
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
      "html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/‌​" +
      "tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span/input"));
    System.out.println(input);
    input.sendKeys("432323");
  }
}
```

I get an error message similar to:

```
{"method":"xpath",
 "selector":"html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody‌​/tr[1]/td[1]/span[2]/a[2]"}
```

Comment: Please provide details about the task you need to accomplish and tools you use.

Comment: I need to enter the Customer id textbox and perform action on submit button. so for that i am not able to find xpath to pass.

Comment: When i am passing the direct xpath then getting this error = Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span[2]/a[2]"}

Comment: Hello Team help me out to find this ASAP

Comment: for this i need xpath to create = <input class="input_password" type="text" value="" onkeypress="return fSubmit(event);" size="10" maxlength="10" name="fldLoginUserId">

Comment: What tools are you using? E.g. Selenium in Java?

Answer (score 2):

You have got a frames in that page. Use the code below, it works on HDFC net banking.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(1); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='input_password']")).sendKeys("abcd");
```

Full code:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.hdfcbank.com/assets/popuppages/netbanking.htm");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'continue_red')]")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame(1); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='input_password']")).sendKeys("abcd");
```

Answer (score 1):

The XPath expression you showed selects an `<a>` element, whereas you said you want to select an `<input>` element, if I understand you correctly.

Try this XPath expression instead:

```
//input[@class="input_password"]
```

Or you could use a CSS selector, but you haven't told us what tools you're using so it's not clear whether CSS selectors are available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and i tried it and it was not working and the tools i am using is selenium webdriver with eclipse

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='input_password']"}

Comment: @Chandan: Please show the code that throws this exception.

Comment: Hi Larsh here the code---------
public class test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/");
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span/input"));
  System.out.println(input);
  input.sendKeys("432323");
 }

}

Comment: @Chandan: I will edit your question to put your code in there, because I guess you don't have enough rep to be able to do that. My next question would be, is driver.get() returning a normal page? is it returning anything, vs. timing out? Is it returning a 404 page? Can you get your program to display the content returned by the get(), so you can see whether your desired `<input>` element is present?